# Why do different data types take more memory for the same data?

Tags: memory, types, language-agnostic, primitive-types, information-theory

For example, if I want to store the number one, I can use an `integer type`, taking up **32-bits** or a `long type`, taking up **64-bits**, however there will be **the same amount of information** (from a symbolic perspective) on both data types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable occupies space based on the **type**, not the actually contained **value**.
From the type depends the totality of possible values, of which the current actual value is just one. So the definition set requires a certain amount of space, not the value itself.

**EDIT**:

I sense confusion :)

Let's say we have 2 bits which can be combined in 4 ways:

```
00
01
10
11
```

Now these are all possible combinations of 2 bits.
What those **represent** is completely indifferent. We just have 4 different states. We can map those to whatever we want:

```
00 white
01 black
10 red
11 blue
```

or

```
00 A
01 B
10 C
11 D
```

or

```
00 0
01 1
10 2
11 3
```

The fact that we can encode those 4 states is bound to the type. Whatever value we store in a variable of that type will always occupy all 2 bits that are necessary to encode all 4 possible values.

A remarkable exception are strings. They can be seen as a *modern* implementation of Turing's **finite** tape on which to inscribe characters from an alphabet. Remarkably, we can store all human knowledge with that type (e.G. the totality of all written books could be stored in one single string).

Comment: So it's based on a set of definitions that are inherently built into the type to transform the stored value to the true value?

Comment: No. [Dichotomy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichotomy) requires two distinguishable states of information. Thus, at least a bit is needed to store the state. To distinguish 2^n states, you'll need n bits. That's how the universe works in which you were born. No way around this. So if you have a type that can encode 1024 different states, you need at least 10 bits. This is all [combinatorics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics) and [information theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory).

Comment: Ok, understood now. I was a bit confused when you said definition set, I was thinking of a lookup table.